# Loop through JSON file in bash script

Tags: bash, jq

I have a bash script that user enter name of a database and then my script needs to loop through this database config file. my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "_id":1,
    "db_name":"postgres",
    "username":"postgres_user",
    "password":"postgres_pass",
    "daily" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [1,2],
               "delete_after" : 14,
               "compressed" : true,
           "path" : "localhost"
         },
    "monthly" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [2,5,30],
               "delete_after" : 7,
               "compressed" : false,
           "path" :" localhost"
         },
    "yearly" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [100],
               "delete_after" : 14,
               "compressed" : true,
           "path" : "localhost"
          }
}
{
    "_id":2,
    "db_name":"test",
    "username":"test_user",
    "password":"test_pass",
    "daily" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [1,7],
               "delete_after" : 14,
               "compressed" : true,
           "path" : "localhost"
           },

    "monthly" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [2,5,25],
               "delete_after" : 7,
               "compressed" : false,
           "path" : "localhost"
           },

    "yearly" : {
               "days_to_backup" : [50],
               "delete_after" : 14,
               "compressed" : true,
           "path" : "localhost"
           }


}
```

Now once user run the script with particular database name, i want to loop through the "days_to_backup" numbers and for each day look it it's equal for today date. The problem is that i don't know how to fetch the daily/monthly/yealy.days_to_backup and then loop through the days.
I tried with jq :

```
#! /bin/sh

#monday is first day of the week
export Today=$(date +%d)
while getopts d: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        d) database=${OPTARG};;


    esac
done

if jq .db_name file.json | grep $database
then
        jq 'select(.db_name=="'$database'")' file.json
        ##this one returns the whole document of the specified database
        ##loop here for daily/monthly_yearly.days_to_backup???
else
        echo "database not found"
fi
```

Edit: my input is the name of the database ( " postgres " ) and then i will iterate through the daily/monthly/yearly array and if the number is like current date ( today is 8 of the month) so the output will be - echo "backup today".

Edit2: sorry my bad. for daily it means that day of the week so (1,7) are sunday and saturday and if current date is sunday or saturday i want and echo "backup today". for monthly it means the day of the month, so if i have monthly (01,08) it will echo "backup today" because today is the 8th of the month. and for yearly i want days since the first day of the year.

Ok so I succeeded to loop through the array but the problem now is that it run over the array of the 2 big objects (id 1 + 2)

```
for i in $(jq -r ".daily.days_to_backup | .[]" file.json)
  do
    echo $i "im number"
  done
```

how do I select that it will run only over _id:1 / db_name: postgres?

Comment: Please add to your question example input and your desired output (no description).

Comment: Does this mean that on the 29th of each month you're supposed to do a daily backup and a yearly backup, and on the 30th you're supposed to do a monthly backup?

Comment: edited. when I call the script i specify with -d the name of the database and then for each daily/monthly/yearly.days_to_Backup array i want to check if the number there is same as current date. if yes just print a echo that it's same date.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful with `date +%d` -- for single digit days, you get a leading zero, which might throw off your comparisons.

Comment: You might find [gron](https://github.com/TomNomNom/gron) a bit easier to work with than jq

Comment: I edited the daily,monthly,yearly meaning. I just need help with greping single value in one of those arrays and then i'm ok with checking if the number there is same as the current date of the month/week/year

Comment: Ok so I succeeded to loop through the array but the problem now is that it run over the array of the 2 big objects (id 1 + 2). how do I select specific object?

Comment: @glennjackman `gron` could be a jq filter :)

Comment: ... but I agree that it's probably simpler to use in a reliable way than `jq` in some situations. Didn't know it, thanks! (I just wrote such a jq filter :) )

Answer (score 3):

An efficient approach would be based on using `any`, e.g. along the lines of the following:

```
jq --arg db $database --argjson Today $Today '
    select(.db_name==$db and
           any(.daily[], .monthly[], .yearly[]; . == $Today) ) 
' file.json
```

Note that both parameters ($database and $Today) should be passed in as command-line arguments rather than provided using shell-based string interpolation.  Using --argjson will ensure that any leading 0s in the shell variable $Today do not cause problems.

Note also that the above query will return a stream of 0 or more values.  You might want to guarantee the names are distinct, e.g. by using the jq built-in filter `unique` (defined for arrays), or the stream-oriented filter `uniques` defined in the [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook).

Comment: Could you please explain how `.` can be equal to `$Today` which is a number ?

Comment: Using `--argjson` will in this case ensure Today is a JSON number.

Comment: But `.` is a whole struecture.

Comment: Nope.  Look at the definition of `any/2` in builtin.jq